# Appending item to each list inside of a list

Tags: python, list, datetime

If I have a list like this:

```
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ["00:05:00', '00:04:00']]
```

How can I subtract the first and second number of each list and append the result at the end of each list so that I get:

```
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00', '00:02:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00', '00:01:00']]
```

My current code:

```
end_lst = []
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00']]
for t1, t2 in lst:
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S")
    diff = (d2 - d1)
    end_lst = [item + [diff] for item in lst]
print(end_lst)
```

but the output doesn't come out properly for each list. Any ideas?

Output:

```
[['00:10:00', '00:08:00', datetime.timedelta(-1, 86160)], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00', datetime.timedelta(-1, 86160)]]
```

Comment: What's the output so far? Please edit that in.

Comment: Your lst is incorrect. It should be `lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ["00:05:00', '00:04:00']]'

Comment: You need to format it again after the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the `datetime.timedelta` objects to strings while making sure that `d1` is being subtracted off of `d2`.

```py
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00']]
for t1, t2 in lst:
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S")
    diff = str(d1 - d2) # Only change to your current source code
    end_lst = [item + [diff] for item in lst]
print(end_lst) # [['00:10:00', '00:08:00', '0:02:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00', '0:01:00']]
```

Inspired by @ferhen, you can also use list comprehension to make this more concise, although readability is arguably sacrificed.

```py
end_lst = [[t1, t2, str(datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S"))] for t1, t2 in lst]
print(end_lst) # [['00:10:00', '00:08:00', '0:02:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00', '0:01:00']]
```

Now, this is assuming that the `t1` represents time that is later than `t2`. If not, you might get results such as `'-1 day, 23:59:00'` in your nested list.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

import datetime

```
end_lst = []
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00']]
for tup in lst:
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tup[0], "%H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tup[1], "%H:%M:%S")
    diff = (d1 - d2)
    end_lst = [item + [str(diff)] for item in lst]

print(end_lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy if you treat each element as a list, without unpacking:

```py
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00']]
for internal_list in lst:
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(internal_list[0], "%H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(internal_list[1], "%H:%M:%S")
    diff = (d2 - d1)
    internal_list.append(diff)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```py
end_lst = [[t1, t2, str(datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S"))] for (t1, t2) in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `lst` is incorrect, otherwise your code is fine.

```
import datetime
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ["00:05:00", '00:04:00']]

end_lst = []
lst = [['00:10:00', '00:08:00'], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00']]
for t1, t2 in lst:
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S")
    diff = (d2 - d1)
    end_lst = [item + [diff] for item in lst]
print(end_lst)
```

The output is then:

```
[['00:10:00', '00:08:00', datetime.timedelta(-1, 86340)], ['00:05:00', '00:04:00', datetime.timedelta(-1, 86340)]]
```

The issue then I am guessing is with your timedelta object. You can find the documentation here: [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Here is the Google Colab notebook that I created with your example and the proper edit.
[Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1r8tXdrkL_hAIa-xRWNGgG1pIzzRmRyLS)